# Print p-value in logistic regression MNLogit()

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression, p-value

I have a dataframe that looks like:

I have applied Logistic regression and I want to have the p-score and t value in another dataframe

```
  Algorithm         Success
    A                 0.91
    B                 0.98
    C                 0.76
     .
     .
     .
    B                 0.77
    C                 0.68
    D                 0.43
```

Code:

```
 p1_logit_model=sm.MNLogit(group["Algorithm"], group["Success"].astype(float))
```

Output:

```
       Results: MNLogit
===============================================================
Model:              MNLogit          Pseudo R-squared: 0.104 

  Dependent Variable: algorithm        AIC:              184.2255

Date:               2018-12-18 17:19 BIC:              194.2622
No. Observations:   55               Log-Likelihood:   -87.113 
Df Model:           0                LL-Null:          -97.227 
Df Residuals:       50               LLR p-value:      nan     
Converged:          1.0000           Scale:            1.0000  
No. Iterations:     9.0000    

 --------------------------------------------------------------
  algorithm = 0   Coef.  Std.Err.   t    P>|t|   [0.025 0.975]
 --------------------------------------------------------------
  p1_less100ms      0.2326   0.5804 0.4008 0.6886 -0.9050 1.3702
  --------------------------------------------------------------
  algorithm = 1   Coef.  Std.Err.    t    P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
   --------------------------------------------------------------
  p1_less100ms   -6.3891   3.9519 -1.6167 0.1059 -14.1346 1.3565
```

I want to store the p-value and t-score for each in to a algorithm, can any one help me how?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to fit the model first to access the p-values and t-values. Try this:

```
fit = p1_logit_model.fit()

print(fit.pvalues[i])
print(fit.tvalues[i])
```

where  `i` is the index for whichever category you're interested in looking at from the multinomial model. As a tip, if you're really looking to use a logistic regression model, you should be using `model = sm.Logit(y, X)` instead.

Comment: Can you help me with the lnk that provides relvant documentation to this? Also, somethint that explans the output.

Comment: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.html for the logistic model. Here is a tutorial for using it: http://blog.yhat.com/posts/logistic-regression-and-python.html.

Comment: Hello, Can you please let me know what this values indicate : - [0.025 0.975] and the values below it

Comment: @TjS From what part of the output does it come from?

Comment: It's to the right of P>|t| indicating  [0.025 0.975]. I want to know what it represents, I want to discard to check P-value having less than 0.05 , I am not sure about the representation of the output

Comment: That column shows the 95% confidence intervals of the coefficient. So it can be used to assess how robust the coefficients of the model area.

Comment: Use the P>|t| column to check whether your coefficient has a P-value less than 0.05!

Comment: WHy does it skip the last category?? I have 5 unique categories in the Algorithm, however, I could see the results.summary2() where only 4 and the last category seems missing.

Comment: @TjS Remember, one category is the reference, so it makes sense you only return 4.

Comment: Ohh. So this is also comparing pairwise. I want to have comparison for all categories against 'Success' .  Here, this is comparing one of the algorithm against all other algorithms.

Comment: Can you help me in changing the reference category everytime maybe using a loop or something

Comment: I don’t think you can change it explicitly with statsmodel which is weird, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096234/python-multinomial-logit-with-statsmodels-module-change-base-value-of-mlogit-re

Comment: I tried adding values dummy to the dataframe at the end but it still manages to pickup the same category